# Couldn't find Tour without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on an app to book different types of tours. I have 3 tables - 1) reservations 2) tours 3) join table (reservations_tours). I'm trying to pass the tour id to reservations, but keep getting this error:

```
Couldn't find Tour without an ID
app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

**Reservations controller:**

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
  end

  def create
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    #@reservation.tour = @tour # associate @reservation with video
    if @reservation.save
      Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]
      Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => 9000, # amount in cents, again
        :currency => "usd",
        :card => params[:stripeToken]    # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
      )
      flash[:success] = "Your reservation has been booked for #{@reservation.date} for #{@reservation.passengers} person(s). Please save this info."
      redirect_to new_tour_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:date, :passengers)
  end
end
```

**Tours controller:**

```
class ToursController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @tour = Tour.new
  end

  def create
    @tour = Tour.new(tours_params)
    if @tour.save
      flash[:success] = "Tour #{@tour.name} has been successfully added."
      redirect_to new_tour_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "The tour #{@tour.name} was not successfully saved. Please try again"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  private

  def tours_params
    params.require(:tour).permit(:name, :amount)
  end
end
```

**Reservations view (new)**

```
= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/"

= javascript_include_tag 'payment'

:javascript
  Stripe.setPublishableKey("#{ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY']}");

.container
  .row
    .col-md-9
      %h2= @tour.name
    .col-md-3
      %p= @tour.amount

      = bootstrap_form_for(@reservation, html: { class: 'form-horizontal', id: 'payment-form'}) do |f|
        = f.alert_message 'Please fix the errors below:'
        = f.text_field :date
        = f.text_field :passengers
        %fieldset.credit_card
          %span.payment-errors
        .control-group
          = label_tag :card_number, 'Credit card number:', class: 'control-label'
          .controls
            = text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: 'span3', data: {stripe: 'number'}
        .control-group
          = label_tag :security_code, 'Security code:', class: 'control-label'
          .controls
            = text_field_tag :security_code, nil, name: nil, class: 'span3', data: {stripe: 'cvc'}
        .control-group
          = label_tag :exp_date, 'Expiration:', class: 'control-label'
          .controls
            = select_month(Date.today, {add_month_numbers: true},  class: 'span2', data: {stripe: 'exp-month'})
            = select_year(Date.today.year, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 4}, class: 'span1', data: {stripe: 'exp-year'})
        %fieldset.actions.control-group
          .controls
            = f.submit 'Sign up'
```

**Reservation model:**

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations_tours, foreign_key: 'reservation_id'
  has_many :tours, through: :reservations_tours
end
```

**Tour model**

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations_tours, foreign_key: 'tour_id'
  has_many :reservations, through: :reservations_tours
end
```

**Join table**

```
class ReservationsTours < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reservation, foreign_key: 'reservation_id'
  belongs_to :tour, foreign_key: 'tour_id'
end
```

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :reservations, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :tours
end
```

Comment: Please provide the source code for your new reservations page.

Comment: params[:tour_id] is nil

Comment: Why does a reservation have multiple tours? My gut tells me it should be one to many, not many to many. You could simplify a lot by getting rid of the join table, adding the foreign_key to the reservations table and using nested resources.

Comment: As @fotanus said, you're not passing `tour_id` from your new reservation page.

Comment: Yes, now that I think about it should be a one to many relationship. I will adjust that. In the mean time, I have updated the post with reservations #new. Yes, the tour_id isn't getting passed in, but I'm not sure sure why?

Comment: because `tour_id ` is not present in the url or form

Comment: Do you mind explaining the proper way to pass in tour_id?

Comment: I explained the two most used ways below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a non existing relation. You have two basic options to create a relation in rails:

1. Provide a [dropdown](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) with existing tours in the reservations form

   `f.collection_select(:tour_id, Tour.all, :id, :name)`

   it will become available in the `params[:reservation]` array. You will have to permit the `tour_id` param in `reservation_params`
2. make a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for reservations in `config/routes.rb`.

   ```
   resources :tours do
     resources :reservations
   end
   ```

   which will give you a POST url like `/tours/:tour_id/reservations` and provide you with `params[:tour_id]`

Comment: Thank you, that did it! I also had to change my form_for to accommodate the nested resources - like so: bootstrap_form_for([:tour, @reservation] Please let me know if this is the correct way to go about it. Thank you again!